Qt6/PyQt6: Cannot expand folder in tree view for regular user (but root user works fine)
How can I expand file system folders in tree view for a regular user like I can with folders owned by root?

I have a QTreeView displaying a QFileSystemModel(QSortFilterProxyModel). Double clicking on a folder owned by root expands the folder, but double clicking on the folder owned by brian (i.e., my current user) enters an edit mode on the text of the directory name but does not expand the directory.
The following folders are identical except for the user/group ownership.
/_test_root_user:
.rw-r--r-- 0 root root 16 Dec 17:43 test.txt

/_test_brian_user:
.rw-r--r-- 0 brian brian 16 Dec 17:43 test.txt





Solution
The default properties created for a QTreeView object in Qt Designer include QAbstractItemView -> editTriggers -> DoubleClicked by default. De-selecting this property eliminates entry into edit mode and allows opening of folders having root and regular user ownership in the same way. It remains unclear to me, however, why folder ownership would cause the different opening behavior in the first place.


Ownership affects the editing behaviour, not the opening behaviour. You cannot edit folders without the necessary permissions. By default, editing takes priority over opening.
